# Files missing from NTFS drive and drive is split into many

Tags: files, ntfs

Using kali linux 1.0 in dual boot with windows 8. I have an NTFS partition (D: on windows) I usually mount it on both OS. I face the following problem
1. cannot access some folders in NTFS partition. (unable to see them on linux but works fine with windows). I don't face any errors while mounting it.
also my /media directory shows 3 files with same name which represent my D: (ntfs drive m talking about)
here is output of `ls` command in `/media` directory

```
root@code:/media# ls
01CD1F0FE77B9960   01CD1F0FE77B9960__  cdrom0       usb   usb1
01CD1F0FE77B9960_  cdrom               truecrypt11  usb0
```

01CD1F0FE77B9960 is the NTFS partition.
How can i get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it happens but there is a way to handle this.
The 01CD1F0FE77B9960 (D: drive) is here split into three 01CD1F0FE77B9960_, 01CD1F0FE77B9960__ and 01CD1F0FE77B9960. you can browse them from /media directory.
your data is in one of them for sure. 
Also you can merge them from time to time say once in a month.
sources : http://cantstopgeeking.blogspot.in/2014/02/tips-for-linuxwindows8-dual-boot-users.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a total guess but I did come across this thread related to Win8 + NTFS: [How to Mount Windows 8′s OS Partition in Ubuntu (12.10 & 12.04), After ‘Hybrid Boot’ is Used?](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/01/mount-windows-8-partition-ubuntu-hybrid-boot/). I'd be curious if these directories went away with the addition of `remove_hiberfile` to the mounting options for this share.

Also I can't help but notice that `truecrypt11` folder. Are you encrypting either folders or using whole drive encryption on this disk? That would lead me to think that perhaps those files aren't accessible due to the encryption.

Comment: no, m not using truecrypt on my NTFS partition and it occurs even after disabling fast startup feature